# What is happening in a gutter "antenna"?

Tags: antenna

can you explain me what is happening with RF in a iron gutter?

I've tried to simulate with nec2, but I'm just a beginner and doesn't really know all the parameters to come close to reality. This is also for transmission and not receiving.

The gutter looks like on the images.

I've also **connected a 50$\Omega$ coax** around 4-5 meters over ground at the vertical part with a short copper wire around it. Coax ground goes to a short wire radial.
The ending of the vertical iron gutter part is in tar. I don't know if there is plastic down there.
I've measured this with a VNA. And it doesn't look so bad as I've imagined before.

I'd like to use it for SWL. At the moment I have very **weak signals of HAM** stations. Only **HF AM radio** broadcast has **power**. Although I receive some **WSPR bacons** over 1000km, but only in noise level with application. The strongest 80m HAM LSB or CW was maybe 12-15db over noise.

Is it useful to try a **unun/balun**? Does this change anything on receiving? How can I find out if the gutter is balanced or unbalanced? I think it might be unbalanced. But how do I know for sure?

The VNA tells me that it is quite **resonant around 6 MHz**. There are a few more areas with resonance up to UHF.
So would I receive stronger signals if I match it better with an **1:2 or 1:2.5 unun** to come from 10-20$\Omega$ near 50$\Omega$?

Or should I try a **band filter** at the gutter?

Or are the signals weak, because the gutter is **grounded too good**? Would it make sense to strip an **isolated wire** next to the gutter (all the way along). And a longer radial down to 1m over ground? Coming closer to a dipole.
My possibilities are limited. I've no idea how to get a cable to the roof without annoying the neighbors. My balcony is roofed. The garden is small and also used by neighbors.

[image: nec2 simulation]
[image: nec2 radiation simulation]

Comment: While this is not an answer to your question, you might be interested to look at antennas such as the improved version of the Pa0rdt receiving antenna (http://www.pa3fwm.nl/projects/miniwhip/). For listening at the frequencies you seem to be interested in, I've had very good results with these...

Comment: I already think about to give the miniwhip a try. Or some other active antenna. But I've read that the coax cable to the antenna is a big part of the miniwhip. And well, here the cable would be short and next to walls. How do you have/had installed it?

Comment: "Something, probably, I think... I hope!" is what's happening in a gutter antenna, according to most people who set them up :)

Comment: You might try feeding your gutter with a hairpin match, or otherwise experimenting with the feed point. You might add to your question the dimensions of your gutter. Also, how is the copper loop attached to the iron?